# Replay button in html5

Tags: jquery, html

Does the replay button work for audio in HTML 5? When the audio does not finish playing or it finishes playing and then if you click replay the animation and audio should start over.

I have recently used pause and play for this, but I don't know how I can come up with replay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pause").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#play").show();
        $("#aa").stop(true,false);
        audioTag1.pause();
    }); 
    $("#play").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#pause").show();
        animateaa();
    }); 
})
```

Any solutions?

Comment: There he wants to stop the audio all of a sudden and wants to start over. here wherever I stop I should again play the same sound and animation from starting.

Comment: I have checked pause and play for the animation and audio .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243235/html5-audio-how-to-quickly-stop-and-restart-a-clip

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 Button doesnt support a replay button. User has to click the play button again to replay unless we have given loop attribute to video tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).