# Stop audio on click and play it again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using 2 custom buttons and using JavaScript to click the audio play and pause.

I am using the below code for that:

```
<img class="head-iconn" src="img/audio.png" onClick="document.getElementById('audio1_play32').play(); return false;" />
<img class="head-icon2" src="img/audio2.png" onClick="document.getElementById('audio1_play32').pause(); return false;" />
```

But I want to stop the audio instead of pause so that when I play it again, it'll start from the beginning.

I am using this code for that:

```
<img class="head-iconn" src="img/audio.png" onClick="document.getElementById('audio1_play32').play(); return false;" />
<img class="head-icon2" src="img/audio2.png" onClick="document.getElementById('audio1_play32').pause(); document.getElementById('audio1_play32').currentTime = 0;return false;" />
```

and now the audio stops but can not play again when I click on the first button.

This is the audio code I am using:

```
<audio id="audio1_play32" controls>
    <source src="voice/vo1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
```

Can someone please let me know what I am making mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243338/2740650

Comment: Not working. May be some issue in the HTML code I have written

Comment: It worked for me in this sample when I added `x.currentTime = 0;` in the play callback. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play

Comment: For one thing, you have audio1_play32 and audio1_play31 in your sample.  This is why it's a good idea to use a constant to refer to your play and your stop buttons!

Comment: @user2740650 yes it'll play but not from the very beginning. I want to play from beginning each time it starts. Also, the 31 is a typo. I have fixed that in the initial code.

Comment: Sefinitely start with not putting the JS inside HTML attributes, but putting it in its own `index.js` or the like, and loading that with `<script src="index.js" async defer></script>`. Even just keeping them separated so you show your HTML and JS separately to others when you need help is great, aside from all the benefits you get from your code editor being able to flag errors correctly.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes, I'll separate the scripts, but for the initial testing purpose, I have used everything at once to make it work. Once done, I'll separate them

Comment: genuinely no reason to work with a hard-to-work-with solution first though. You're already queryselecting in your attributes instead of just "calling a function" so you'd be much better off switching now rather than "once you're done", so you don't have to work within the limitations of things fitting in an attribute string. And make your question better at the same time, of course, because then you can just show a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

Although not part of the question OP asked,

> *"What is I have multiple audios on a single page?"*

Simply place the event handler on an element that contains all of the `<button>`s. Then get the reference to a specific `<audio>` by proximity of `clicked` `<button>`(`event.target`):

```
<audio><!--mp3 = btnGroup.previousElementSibling--></audio>
<fieldset>
<!--btnGroup = clicked.parentElement-->
  <button><!--clicked = event.target--></button>
</fieldset>
```

---

Stay away from using attribute event handlers:

```
<!-- This is bad -->
<button class='play' onclick='playAudio()'>PLAY</button>
```

Use `.addEventListener()`

```
<button class='play'>PLAY</button>
<script>
  const play = document.querySelector('.play');
  play.addEventListener('click', playAudio);
</script>
```

or property event handlers:

```
<button class='play'>PLAY</button>
<script>
  const play = document.querySelector('.play');
  play.onclick = playAudio;
</script>
```

See [Event Handlers](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#event-handlers)

Keep your JavaScript separate from HTML or you'll cripple the growth of your code. The example below uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to determine which button was clicked and what happens according to what was clicked.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');

const audioControl = event => {
  const clicked = event.target;
  const btnGroup = clicked.parentElement;
  const mp3 = btnGroup.previousElementSibling;

  if (clicked.matches('.play') && !mp3.paused) {
    mp3.pause();
  } else if (clicked.matches('.play') && !mp3.playing) {
    mp3.play();
  } else if (clicked.matches('.stop')) {
    mp3.pause();
    mp3.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

main.onclick = audioControl;
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 4ch
}

fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <audio src='https://soundbible.com/mp3/thunder_strike_1-Mike_Koenig-739781745.mp3'></audio>
  <fieldset>
    <button class='play'>⏯️</button>
    <button class='stop'>⏹️</button>
  </fieldset>

  <audio src='https://soundbible.com/mp3/airplane-landing_daniel_simion.mp3'></audio>
  <fieldset>
    <button class='play'>⏯️</button>
    <button class='stop'>⏹️</button>
  </fieldset>

  <audio src='https://soundbible.com/mp3/old-car-engine_daniel_simion.mp3'></audio>
  <fieldset>
    <button class='play'>⏯️</button>
    <button class='stop'>⏹️</button>
  </fieldset>

</main>
```

Comment: What is I have multiple audios on a single page?

Comment: @Jituu see update