# Why does this audio play() fail on iOS 14?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, html5-audio

I have seen [Why can't JavaScript .play() audio files on iPhone safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776548/why-cant-javascript-play-audio-files-on-iphone-safari) and I know that a user interaction is required before playing an audio object. However, this doesn't work on iOS 14:

```
<div id="a">Click here</div>
<script>
var audio = new Audio('a.mp3');
audio.load();
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() { 
    audio.pause();         // always restart the sound, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243338
    audio.currentTime = 0; 
    audio.play(); 
}
</script>
```

With this code, no sound is produced which clicking/touching on the `<div>`, with an iPhone on iOS 14.

How to solve this?

Comment: Maybe is tab muted or? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Comment: @MiloshN. could the `audio.volume` be 0 by default? this would be strange.

Comment: By the way does this apply to `var audio = new Audio('a.mp3');` instead of a `<audio>` HTML tag?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe that volume is taken from anywhere in safari settings, maybe?

Comment: This works in iOS 14/15 with the code above: https://batman.dev/static/70627754/